# Using comparison operators in Scala's pattern matching system

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Is it possible to match on a comparison using the pattern matching system in Scala?
For example:

```
a match {
    case 10 => println("ten")
    case _ > 10 => println("greater than ten")
    case _ => println("less than ten")
}
```

The second case statement is illegal, but I would like to be able to specify "when a is greater than".

Comment: This can also be used to check if a function evaluates to true, e.g. `case x if x.size > 2 => ...`

Comment: The important thing to understand is that the "patterns" to the left of => operator are indeed "patterns". The 10 in the first case expression you have is NOT the integer literal. So, you can't perform operations (like > check or say function application isOdd(_)) on the left.

Answer (score 317, accepted):

You can add a guard, i.e. an `if` and a boolean expression after the pattern:

```
a match {
    case 10 => println("ten")
    case x if x > 10 => println("greater than ten")
    case _ => println("less than ten")
}
```

Edit: Note that this is more than superficially different to putting an `if` *after* the `=>`, because a pattern *won't* match if the guard is not true.

Comment: Ben, good answer, it really illustrates the importance of pattern guard.

Answer (score 34):

As a non-answer to the question's spirit, which asked how to incorporate predicates into a match clause, in this case the predicate can be factored out before the `match`:

```
def assess(n: Int) {
  println(
    n compare 10 match {
      case 0 => "ten"
      case 1 => "greater than ten"
      case -1 => "less than ten"
    })
}
```

Now, [the documentation for `scala.math.Ordering.compare(T, T)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering) promises only that the non-equal outcomes will be *greater than* or *less than zero*. Java's [`Comparable#compareTo(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) is specified similarly to Scala's. It happens to be conventional to use 1 and -1 for the positive and negative values, respectively, as Scala's [current implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L250) does, but one can't make such an assumption without some risk of the implementation changing out from underneath.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're suggesting this as a real solution, but I would strongly recommend against anything that relies on an undocumented convention or assumption.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I wrote "one can't make such an assumption without some risk", and qualified my answer as a "non-answer". It's interesting to consider *why* `compare()` and `compareTo()` don't specify 0, 1, and -1 as their codomain.

Comment: Math.signum(n compare 10) would guarantee -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: It's common practice not to to return 0, 1, -1. That way you can compare numbers via subtraction. i,e (a - b) returns the right value

Comment: This morning I confirmed that nearly *six years* after writing my original answer, even though the implementation in question moved from one type to another, Scala still maintains that noted behavior of returning -1, 0, or 1.

Comment: A valid answer, but personally I don't like this. It's too easy to forget what 0,1, and -1 are supposed to mean.

Answer (score 27):

A solution that in my opinion is much more readable than adding guards:

```
(n compare 10).signum match {
    case -1 => "less than ten"
    case  0 => "ten"
    case  1 => "greater than ten"
}
```

Notes:

- [`Ordered.compare`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordered@compare(that:A):Int) returns a negative integer if this is less than that, positive if greater, and 
  `0` if equal.
- [`Int.signum`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Int@signum:Int) compresses the output from `compare` to `-1` for a negative number (less than 10), `1` for positive (greater than 10), or `0` for zero (equal to 10).

Answer (score 1):

While all the above and bellow answers perfectly answer the original question, some additional information can be found in the documentation https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html , they didn't fit in my case but because this stackoverflow answer is the first suggestion in Google I would like to post my answer which is a corner case of the question above.
My question is:

- *How to use a guard in match expression with an argument of a
  function?*

Which can be paraphrased:

- *How to use an if statement in match expression with an argument of a
  function?*

The answer is the code example below:

```
    def drop[A](l: List[A], n: Int): List[A] = l match {
      case Nil => sys.error("drop on empty list")
      case xs if n <= 0 => xs
      case _ :: xs => drop(xs, n-1)
    }
```

link to scala fiddle : https://scalafiddle.io/sf/G37THif/2
as you can see the `case xs if n <= 0 => xs` statement is able to use n(argument of a function) with the guard(if) statement.

I hope this helps someone like me.

Answer (score 0):

Scala's pattern matching allows you to define your own extractor.
In this case, you can simply define a new extractor:

```scala
class GreaterThan(n: Int) {
  def unapply(i: Int) = i > n
}

val GreaterThan10 = GreaterThan(10)

a match {
  case 10 => ???
  case GreaterThan10() => ???
  case _ => ???
}
```

or just use pattern guards.