# Pattern matching in scala, check if number greater than

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using comparison operators in Scala’s pattern matching system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585395/using-comparison-operators-in-scalas-pattern-matching-system)

For below method I receive an error : "'=>' expected but integer literal found."

Is it not possible to check if x is greater than another number and or is there an alternative approach to return "greater than 2" if '> 2' is matched ?

```
 def describe(x: Any) = x match {
    case 5 => "five"
    case > 2 => "greater than 2"
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
def describe(x: Any) = x match {
  case 5 => "five"
  case x: Int if (x > 2) => "greater than 2"
}
```

Comment: By the way, that thing called pattern match *guard*.

Comment: Yeah, I added the duplicate, or I would have expanded the answer. I don't think this answer will last very much longer... :-)