# Rounding numeric parameter types in Scala

Tags: scala, switch-statement, conditional-statements, rounding

I'm experimenting with a method in ***Scala*** which is attempting to round numbers depending on how big they are, e.g. if the value is below 1 then it makes sense to round it by at least one decimal point; rather than remaining an integer. Here's what I'm trying:

```
  def roundSmart[A](num: A)(implicit numeric: Numeric[A]) = num match {
    case num if num < 1 => numeric.toDouble(num)
    case _ => numeric.toInt(num)
  }
```

Which throws this error:

> value < is not a member of type parameter A

Of course the parameters need to accept a range of *parameter types* within the *function signature* as it may be taking integers or doubles so this has added a further complexity.

I've taken the *conditional* statement on the first *case* from this answer -
 [Using comparison operators in Scala's pattern matching system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585395/using-comparison-operators-in-scalas-pattern-matching-system/#1585419) and am eager to use a *Functional Programming* approach. Perhaps there is also some in-built scala function like `Math.round()` that could help to round the second *condition* rather than remove any decimals. Thanks!

Comment: `math.round` does exist in scala

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR : every numeric methods you'll need are inside `numeric`

The error is self-explanatory: your type `A` (which is generic) does not have a `<` method.

However, what you have is a typeclass with all numeric methods in it, so you should probably import them:

```
import numeric._
```

This imports (among other things) implicit conversion to `OrderingOps`, which has the desired method. But this comparison cannot work, since `1` is not an `A`, it's an `Int`!

The solution is simply to use `fromInt`of `numeric`.

While we're at it, you will have unexpected results for input such as `-234.2e123`... You'd better do your test on the absolute value of your number (`abs` is also a method of `numeric`).

Also, if you want to do a simple test, there is no need to use pattern matching, a `if else` statement is enough

```
def roundSmart[A](num: A)(implicit numeric: Numeric[A]) = {
  import numeric._
  if (abs(num) < fromInt(1)) toDouble(num) else toInt(num)
}
```

Comment: Note that the return type will be `Double`, you might want to do something about this too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the error goes - great - however if it always returns a `Double` regardless of whether I wanted an `Integer` then it doesn't help to accomplish what I intend to do (please read the whole question to understand the purpose). So I must be using the wrong technique. Also the *pattern matching* is because I will have more than two conditions.

Comment: Since you have static typing, there must be a well defined return type. You should think about what you want it to be, depending on your use case.